# "Handler type is mismatched" when adding SelectionChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing some simple exercises learning WPF & C#. Currently, I'm trying to use a ListBox of all the available system fonts to let the user change the font used in a Button. VS19 has no issues with my code before I compile, but at runtime before the app displays, I get an error reading "Handler type is mismatched" on the line where I call `AddHandler()`. Here is my code:

```
public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies) {
                myFonts.Items.Add(fontFamily.Source); // myFonts is a ListBox
            }
            myFonts.AddHandler(TextBox.SelectionChangedEvent, new SelectionChangedEventHandler(when_selection_changed));
        }

        private void when_selection_changed(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            ListBoxItem lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
            myButton.FontFamily = new FontFamily(lbi.Content.ToString());
        }
```

I do not understand why this results in an error. (I know the foreach block is inelegant, this is purely for experimenting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, Welcome to WPF!

Your problem is: [`TextBox.SelectionChangedEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionchanged), that's the wrong event. You want [`ListBox.SelectionChangedEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged). Though they both share the same name, they are different events with different signatures, hence the exception.

---

As a side, event handlers like this are usually linked up in the XAML, like so:

```
<ListBox Name="myFonts" SelectionChanged="when_selection_changed"/>
```

This will make it much harder to accidentally declare the wrong arguments for the event handler, as it will show up as a compile error.